# QTextBrowser insertPlainText() insert much data causes NO RESPONSE

Tags: qt, qtextbrowser

I use `insertPlainText()` to insert data to QTextBrowser in the slot function, but It seems result in lag even no response along with data increasement. But when I add `'\n'` at the end of data to simulate the `append()`, the lag phenomenon disappeared. But I don't want to add a new line, how to solve this problem?

I tried to use `qApp->processEvents()` after the `insertPlainText()`, but it cause crash.

I tried to start a timer to run `qApp->processEvents()` to refresh the UI, but it didn't solve the problem.

Should I start a new thread to receive serial port data? But the inserted data(I mean received data) size is not big, but the total data size in the browser is big. Receive data may not cost a lot of time.

Comment: How much data do you store in the text browser and how much are you going to insert?

Comment: Can you include the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

`insertPlainText()` performed not well in my machine(i7,16G). It will take about 100ms to insert data when the total data length is about 4096 bytes. I tried the `QScintilla` open source widget which is better but still not perfect. So I think maybe it's wrong thoughts to use `insertPlainText()`.

I changed my thoughts. I use `QByteArray` to store all data and use `setText()` to display the recent 4096 bytes. It looks like I divide the data into many pages and display the recent page. This method solved the problem of how to store the much data. But there is another little problem is that 4096 bytes data can not fill up my screen when I maximize my application. It's not looking good but more data will result in slow response because the app has high data refresh frequency.